# How to add markers/hotspots in a-frame panaroma?

Tags: aframe

I was trying to find a suitable web framework for VR experience and it should work on PC, and mobiles (i am using ionic). i tried many canvas/webGL based tools, finally stumbled upon aframe. i really like this, but i need help on `how to add markers to a panorama image` and also `is it possible to toggle gyroscope on mobile devices` ?

Comment: I think you want to know how to calculate the position of the point in panaroma. [Calculate the position of an element inside a photosphere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123606/calculate-the-position-of-an-element-inside-a-photosphere/41134342#41134342).

Comment: is it possible to open a small popup when i click the marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide in the docs has an example:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/guides/building-with-components.html

https://github.com/aframevr/360-image-gallery-boilerplate

In this example, you place planes. You use the cursor component for gaze-based cursor. And do stuff on mouseenter/mouseleave/click. It uses a lot of components, but that's what it looks like:

```
        <a-entity class="link"
            geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1"
            material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb}"
            event-set__1="_event: mousedown; scale: 1 1 1"
            event-set__2="_event: mouseup; scale: 1.2 1.2 1"
            event-set__3="_event: mouseenter; scale: 1.2 1.2 1"
            event-set__4="_event: mouseleave; scale: 1 1 1"
            set-image="on: click; target: #image-360; src: ${src}"
        </script>
```